# What is a snic in the python psutil module

Tags: python, networking, psutil

I'm writing a python script with the psutil module that monitors some of the running specs of my web servers, for example cpu usage, memory usage and disk usage. One information I want to get from the script is all the ip addresses associated with my network interface cards.

This is how I do it:

```
import psutil

ifcs = psutil.net_if_addrs()
IPs = []

for ifc in ifcs:
    for snic in ifcs[ifc]:
        IPs.append(snic.address)
```

My question is, what is the snic object refering to in the real world? It seems that each physical network card has a few snics attached to it. If I only want to get the snics with the IPv4 address, as those were the ones in real usage, how do I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question. I don't understand what "snic" means. I created a issue https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1273

Answer (score 2):

It stands for s**ystem network interface card**

See: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1273#issuecomment-386563319